# Running multiple long-running tasks as a transaction in TPL C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, parallel-processing, multitasking, task-parallel-library

I have a list of n tasks that I want to execute in parallel, asyncronously.

Each of the parallel running tasks can have 1 or more nested tasks.

I also need to wait and analyse the return result of each Task.
The entire operation is successful only if all tasks execute successfuly (e.g. they return "true").

**Effectively, this is a transactional operation where I need to wait for many tasks to complete sucessfully.**

The problem is that each task may take 1-3 hours to complete (some tasks may take only minutes, while others take hours)
The whole operation might take a full work day.

**My questions:**

> 1. Is this approach feasable and doable using Task Parallel Library?
> 2. Also, what
>      happens if one of the tasks times out and fails to report back to the
>      mother task?
> 3. Can the library handle such scenarios where tasks are not
>      only nested, but alos take a very long time to complete?

**EDIT:**
I found [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/22/9791840.aspx) about cancelling tasks, especially long running ones.
Maybe it useful to others, too.

Comment: Is a SQL transaction (or any remote transaction) going to be involved here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for [`Task.WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx)?

If a task actually times out - i.e. faults - then an `AggregateException` will be thrown. Note that `WaitAll` will wait for *all* the tasks to finish in one way or other before returning, even if some tasks fail early.

I have no reason to believe that TPL has any problem with tasks which take a very long time.

Comment: Yes and no. I'm not looking for TPL features per se; I am asking about how reliably tasks (most of all nested tasks) can report back to their parent task, and what problems you might run into. For instance, when a task is cancelled or timed out, do the other tasks (nested or not) still run to completion (even though it's not neccessary because one of them already failed)?

Comment: @John: In this case they would keep running because you're using `WaitAll`. You could use `WaitAny` instead, and then make the caller notice the failure and use the normal TPL cancellation mechanisms to cancel the other tasks. I don't know whether there's a built-in "cancel all of these if any of them fails" approach. With `WaitAny` you'd need to keep an ever-decreasing set of "still in progress" tasks and only really finish when all of them have succeeded, btw.